# How is memory managed during C++ copy elision?

Tags: c++, c++11, copy-elision

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
public :
    A()
    {
        cout<<"constructor is called"<<endl;
    }
    
    ~A()
    {
        cout<<"destructor is called"<<endl;
    }
    
    A(const A &s)
    {
        cout<<"copy constructor is called"<<endl;
    }
};

A beta()
{
    A a;
    cout<<"mem location a : "<<&a<<endl;
    return a;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    A b = beta();
    cout<<"mem location b : "<<&b<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The above program generates the following output :

```
constructor is called
mem location a : 0x7ffc12bdaf77
mem location b : 0x7ffc12bdaf77
destructor is called
```

As far as I understand just a single instance of A was created rather than 2 instances for **A a** and **A b**, because of copy elision or return value optimisation.
But looking at above program from a memory perspective, *object a is inside the stack activation record or stack space of function beta and has a memory location 0x7ffc12bdaf77* . When it returns from beta, copy elision makes object b just same as object a rather than copying it. So, now *b also has the address 0x7ffc12bdaf77* . I am unable to understand i*f b is still a local of the function main and present inside its stack space, how can it occupy a memory outside main's stack space* ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider this line: `A b = beta();`. How does a compiler implement that?

Well, `beta` is some other function. And `beta` has a return value that is an `A`. So there are two possible ways to implement this. The compiler could make `beta` allocate the stack space for its `A` return value, but that could be problematic since the caller needs to use that return value. So instead, the compiler makes the *caller* allocate the stack space for the return value. After all, the caller does know the size/alignment of the return value, so it has everything it needs to know to allocate that space.

So let's go with the latter. This means that when the compiler calls `beta`, it passes in the address where `beta`'s return value will be. But this also means that the compiler, for this particular call of `beta` could just give `beta`'s return value the same address as it will give `b`.

So right there, we've elided the copy from the return value of the function into `b`.

So when the compiler goes to compile `beta`, it knows that the caller is going to give it a pointer to where the return value should go. So the `return a;` statement semantically copies from the `a` variable into this return value object.

But, the compiler can see the entirety of `beta`. And it can see that the `a` variable is a local variable, and it gets returned on all control paths. So instead of giving `a` a separate stack address, the compiler could just put `a` in the memory provided by the caller for the return value.

So again, we have elided a copy from `a` into the return value.

Answer (score 3):

In the microsoft x64 calling convention, a hidden pointer will be prepended as the first argument to `beta`. This pointer contains the address of `b`, which will be on `main`'s stack frame. This pointer will be used to immediately create both `a` and `b` at the same time on `main`'s stack frame. So in other words, `a` *doesn't* exist anywhere on `beta`'s stack frame; from a memory perspective `a` and `b` will be equivalent.

Comment: This surprises me. How do compilers that can only see a _declaration_ of the function know about this hidden pointer? Or is there always a pointer passed for _optional_ filling of a copy-elided return value?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: Because that's how a compiler compiles functions that return a value (or rather a value that's either too big or too complex to fit into a register). It's part of the calling convention, and that's determined entirely by the function's declaration.

Comment: @NicolBolas Okay, so it's a built-in nature of how return values are implemented by that ABI in all cases? Makes sense. I was confused because, pre-C++17, NRVO was an "optimisation" and thus you'd generally need the function definition to know whether it could be done (and, even then, it "may" not have been done). But, on further reflection, I guess there was never any other way to implement this in general? For exactly that reason. :D

Comment: It occurs to me then that the C++17 "guaranteed elision" rules require this to be the case, and that therefore every C++ ABI must work this way, not just MS's x64 calling convention? (as I'm not aware of any ABI breakage for C++17 on any mainstream playform)

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: Remember that, according to C++, there are *two* copies: the copy from the return to the return value object, and the copy from the return value object to the stack variable at the receiving end. The implementation of the function can elide one, and the receiver can elide the other. If both are elided, then there's full elision.

Answer (score 0):

> As far as I understand just a single instance of A was created rather than 2

Correct.

> how can it occupy a memory outside main's stack space ?

It doesn't.

The return value is simply created in the stack frame of the `main` call.